# rails - How to inject with space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I need to inject something like this in erb:

```
"This is item number 3"
```

So I used:

```
<%= t(:this_is_item_number) + " " + @item.id %>
```

Is there a better way to add space inside the injection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**en.yml**

```
en:
  this_is_item_number: This is item number %{number}
```

***.erb**

```
<%= t(:this_is_item_number, number: 3) %>
```

**result**

> This is item number 3

Comment: Please mark it as answered if you feel this is the right solution for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You frequently see

```
"#{t(:this_is_item_number)} #{@item.id}"
```